# VueJs - Data from API call doesn't reach 2nd API call first time

Tags: vue.js, axios, setinterval

I have 2 API calls, the second call runs with a interval of x seconds and depends on data that comes from the first call. Now i want the first time to run this interval instantly and i can't get this to work properly.

Did some searching and apparently there are a multiple solutions to this and i tried:
- Run the function once before the interval
- setTimeout in the function

These options should work but for some reason the data from the first call that i need for the second call is not making it there.

```
created() {
  this.fetchId();
  this.fetchItems(); //this doesn't get the id set in fetchId()
  setInterval(
    function() {
      this.fetchItems();
    }.bind(this),
    50000
  );
},
methods: {
  fetchId() {
    axios
      .get("two/id")
      .then(response => {
        this.id = response.data.id;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
  fetchItems() {
    axios
      .get("one/api/public-stash-tabs?id=" + this.id)
      .then(response => {
        //do something
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

So this way, the this.id that i need in the fetchItems().axios.get(..) is not working the first time it is ran before the interval. Everything works fine when i remove this function call and just wait the first x seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `axios.get(...)` is an asynchronous call, which means that `fetchId()` method will run in the background while `fetchItems()` method is called immediately after `fetchId()` even before `this.id` is set, so in `fetchItems()` method `this.id` is always undefined. You can fix this by using `async/await` like:

```
created() {
    this.init();            // use a wrapper method here
  },
  methods: {
    async init() {          // using async method here
      await this.fetchId(); // wait for fetchId call to finish
      this.fetchItems();
    },
    fetchId() {
      return axios          // return the promise here, so that we can await on it
        .get("two/id")
        .then(response => {
          this.id = response.data.id;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    },
    fetchItems() {
      axios
        .get("one/api/public-stash-tabs?id=" + this.id)
        .then(response => {
          //do something
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi palaѕн! Thanks for the great answer, with the explanation and the comments in code really helps me understand!